# Express, authorizing a user to see only its data

Tags: node.js, express, authorization

It would be really useful to have some resources and hints on this, because at this moment all I am doing is writing a middleware before every API that does queries to check whether the user is allowed to see the requested data or not.

I have searched, but wasn't able to find a proper guide or tutorial on this.

For instance: I have an application with users, how do I make sure the user can only see its data (so with its ID) when it comes to API `/users/:id`?

Answer (score 0):

you can have a middleware module which test each request and verify if the user has permission or not like this one:

```
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var db = require('../../config/db');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var user = require('../models/user');

function chkRole(roles, role) {
    var r = roles.filter(function(e) {
    return e === role;
    });
    return r.length > 0;
}

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Cache-Control', 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    res.header('Expires', '-1');
    res.header('Pragma', 'no-cache');

    var t = req.headers['cookie'] ? req.headers['cookie'].split(";")[0].split("=")[1] : null;
    var token = (req.body && req.body.access_token) || (req.query && req.query.access_token) || req.headers['x-access-token'] || t;
    if (token) {
    try {
        var U = jwt.decode(token, db.secret);
        if (U.exp <= Date.now()) {
    res.status(400);
    res.json({
        "status" : 400,
        "message" : "Token Expired"
    });
    }
    var roles;
    user.findOne({
    email : U.email
    }, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    if (!user) {
        res.status(401);
        res.json({
        "status" : 401,
        "message" : "Invalid credentials"
        });
        console.log(res.status);
    } else {
        if (U.pass === user.password) {
        if (chkRole(user.roles, 'admin') && (req.url.indexOf('/api/admin/') >= 0)) {
            next();
        } else if ((chkRole(user.roles, 'player') || chkRole(user.roles, 'admin')) && (req.url.indexOf('/api/game/') >= 0)) {
            GLOBAL.email = user.email;
            next();
        } else {
            res.status(403);
            res.json({
            "status" : 403,
            "message" : "Not Authorized"
            });
        }
        }
    }
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(500);
    res.json({
    "status" : 500,
    "message" : "Oops something went wrong",
    "error" : err
    });
}
} else {
res.status(401);
res.json({
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Invalid Token or Key"
});
}
};
```

you can register it in the application main `app.js` file by adding the following line

```
app.all('/api/*', [ require('./app/middlewares/validateRequest') ]);
```